# login issue; dual accounts

Tags: support, login, merge

Sorry! Logged in w/Launchpad apparently created a new ID for me instead of merge. Please merge TyphSniftR and typhaneic at gmail.com. I am
on stackoverflow, ubuntu, linux, launchpad, github, etc. w/ same email, same handle, same name

Comment: You need to use the contact us link at the bottom of the page to contact Stack Exchange support to get an account merge done